# Reference to an instance method of a particular object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

In the following code, it works when passing the method reference variable with the class name, but when passing the reference variable with a user object there is an error.

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }    
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u1 = new User("AAA");
        User u2 = new User("BBB");
        User u3 = new User("ZZZ");

        List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3);        

        userList.forEach(User::printName); // works
        userList.forEach(u1::printName); // compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to *mean* to pass in `u1::printName`? Would you expect it to print "AAA" three times? If not, how do you expect `forEach` to provide the `printName` method with the right user to call `printName` on?

Comment: Yes, i expect to print "AAA", three times. It's just a test, i'm studying

Comment: Okay - so what did you expect `forEach` to do with each of the users that it's iterating over? (See my answer for more details.)

Comment: Actually, i'm not interested in the values ​​that will be produced but in how to use method reference with objects instantiated instead of the class name. Your answer was perfect, now I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`userList.forEach` is expecting a `Consumer<? extends User>` - in other words, a method which accept a `User` reference and do something with it.

That could be:

- A static method accepting a `User` parameter, in which case the parameter will be populated with the relevant element in the list on each iteration:

  ```
  staticMethod(userFromList)
  ```
- An instance method (of any class) accepting a `User` parameter, provided with a *specific* instance to call it on - again, the parameter will be populated with the relevant element:

  ```
  target.instanceMethod(userFromList)
  ```
- An instance method on `User` with *no* parameters, provided *without* a specific instance, which case the *target* of the method call will be the relevant element in the list on each iteration:

  ```
  userFromList.instanceMethod()
  ```

Because you've tried to specify a target *and* the method doesn't have any parameters, the `forEach` method has nothing it can do with each element - it can't pass it as an argument because the method doesn't have any parameters, and it can't use it as the method target because you've already specified one.

Your working code shows the third example. Here are two other methods to allow you to demonstrate the first two:

```
public class UserPrinter {
    private final String name;

    public UserPrinter(String name) {
        this.name;
    }

    public static void staticPrintUser(User user) {
        // Assuming you add a User.getName() method
        System.out.println("staticPrintUser: " + user.getName());
    }

    public void instancePrintUser(User user) {
        System.out.println("instancePrintUser (instance " + name + "): "
            + user.getName());
    }
}
```

Then:

```
userList.forEach(UserPrinter::staticPrintUser);    // equivalent to
//userList.forEach(p -> UserPrinter.staticPrintUser(p));
UserPrinter printer = new UserPrinter("my printer");
userList.forEach(printer::instancePrintUser);      // equivalent to
//userList.forEach(p -> printer.instancePrintUser(p));
```

If you *really* want to call `printUser` on the same `User` three times, ignoring the `User` in the list, you could use:

```
userList.forEach(ignored -> u1.printName());
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html we know that method references are similar to following lambdas

```
method reference          ==> lambda
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
object::method            ==> (Foo f, Bar b, Baz z) -> object.method(f,b,z)
SomeClass::staticMethod   ==> (Foo f, Bar b, Baz z) -> SomeClass.staticMethod(f,b,z)
SomeClass::instanceMethod ==> (Foo f, Bar b, Baz z) -> f.instanceMethod(b,z)
SomeClass::new            ==> (Foo f, Bar b, Baz z) -> new SomeClass(f,b,z)
```

So your code

```
userList.forEach(User::printName); // works
```

can be rewritten as

```
userList.forEach((User u) -> u.printName()); // works
```

which is OK because it means that in `accept` method of `Consumer` which this lambdas "implements" you will invoke `printName()` on each `User` passed to this method.

But in case of

```
userList.forEach(u1::printName); // compile error
```

this code represents following lambda

```
userList.forEach((User u) -> u1.printName(u)); // compile error
//                                       ^^^   // method doesn't accept User argument
```

so you are trying to invoke `printName` from instance held by `u1` reference and pass each `User` from list as this method argument, but as you see

```
public void printName()
```

can't accept instance of `User` as its argument, which is why you are seeing compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
u1::printName
```

is a method reference to be invoked on the object referenced by `ui`. The compiler doesn't know how to interpret the argument it should pass to the `Consumer` lambda. Its best guess is that it should be passed as

```
u1.printName(arg);
```

but such a method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The method reference

```
u1::printName
```

is essentially equivalent to this lambda:

```
() -> u1.printName()
```

This is because `printName` doesn't have any arguments.  If you had a `printNameWithWidth(int width)` method, then `u1::printNameWithWidth` would be equivalent to

```
(int width) -> u1.printNameWithWidth(width)
```

But the point is that in neither case is a `User` one of the arguments, since you've already told it which `User` to use (i.e. `u1`).  `forEach` doesn't like that.  It needs a lambda (or the equivalent) with a `User` (or whatever other element type) as an argument.

This:

```
User::printName
```

is equivalent to

```
(User x) -> x.printName()
```

which is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Testing {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
        B b1=new B(); b1.setName("Durgesh");
        B b2=new B(); b2.setName("Val");
        list.add(b1);list.add(b2);


        MyInterface<B> my1 = B :: printName;
        my1.dummyDisplay(b1,b2);


        MyInterface<B> my2 = (a,b) -> a.printName(b);
        my2.dummyDisplay(b1,b2);

    //  MyInterface<B> my3 = b1::printName;   //compilation error
    }

}

class B{
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public     void printName(B b) {
    System.out.println(this.name + b.name);
    }   
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface  MyInterface <T> {
    public void dummyDisplay(T s, T t);

}
```

Below lines of code works fine even though printName method of class B accepts only 1 parameter while method dummyDisplay accepts 2 parameters. It is because when we call dummyDisplay ( of functional interface ) method with 2 arguments, compiler uses one argument to invoke printName method and another argument is passed as an argument to printName method. That means (arg1).printName(arg2). Notice the usage of "this" keyword in the method printName.So always remember that in such kinds of method references, number of paramters of the method to be called(printName) should always  be 1 less than the number of parameters used in method(dummyDisplay) of functional interface. Such kind of method reference is very frequently used when dealing with POJO  classes where we use getters(no arg) of the classes given the functional interface(say Function/Consumer - having methods with 1 parameter).

```
    MyInterface<B> my1 = B :: printName;
    my1.dummyDisplay(b1,b2);
```

I hope you understand this concept.

Now coming to below lines of code. This code is just a replacement of method reference which we discussed just now. Here, since method declared in functional interface has 2 parameters, so we have to and had to use 2 arguments in lambda expression (in this  case its a and b). Then a.printName(b) will be written as the definition of interface method (dummyDisplay). Its straight forward. Lambda expression can be used any where provided Functional interfaces(off course).

```
    MyInterface<B> my2 = (a,b) -> a.printName(b);
    my2.dummyDisplay(b1,b2);
```

Now coming to last piece of code. We get compilation error because compiler expects exactly the same number of parameters in printName method of class B which are there in the method of functional interface. Normally this kind of method reference is used just to call any random method of any class which accepts some parameters and does some  processing on the accepted data. eg. say add/multiply/divide methods present in the class Calculate or the compare method of Comparator functional interface. In all these cases, method definition does not use "this" keyword. It simply accepts some parameters and performs some task on them. I hope you guys got something  out of it.

```
MyInterface<B> my3 = b1::printName;   //compilation error
```

Having said this, Now lets come to your question,

```
userList.forEach(User::printName);
```

works fine because, forEach method internally calls a method accept(arg1) of Consumer interface and your user-defined method printName has no args. So as per my above explanation, it is correct and the compiler does not complaint.

and

```
userList.forEach(u1::printName);
```

gives compilation error, because you are using object u1 while referencing instance method printName . So compiler expects same number of parameters of printName method as that there are in accept method of Consumer interface. So it will try to find printName(User param1) from your class User. And since it is not found, compiler complaints about the same.

I hope this helps you guys. Also let me know  if I have missed anything or if I have said some thing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the key point of usage of method references in Java. I had really difficulty in learning it. [@Pshemo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25409946/4990642) is really nice source for this case. Besides, the following image excerpted from [Java 8 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-8-in-action) is helpful to remember.

[image]